# Laravel 5.1 & Socialite - How to connect Facebook/Twitter details to currently authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I've implemented Socialite fine and works for new users or users that have the same Facebook email address as the email address in my apps database.

However, some users will have a different Facebook email account to the account they use in my app. I would like to allow users to connect their facebook profile to their app account when they are logged in.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('login/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

redirectToProvider code:

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
```

Below is my current code that handles the socialite user creation/update:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

        $user_query = User::where('email', $user->email)
            ->orWhere('oauth_facebook_id', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('oauth_twitter_id', $user->id)
            ->get();

        if($user_query->count() > 0) {

            $the_user = $user_query->first();

            if($provider === 'facebook') {
                $the_user->oauth_facebook_id = $user->id;
            }

            if($provider === 'twitter') {
                $the_user->oauth_twitter_id = $user->id;
            }

            $the_user->avatar = $user->avatar;

            $the_user->save();

            \Auth::login($the_user, true);

            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        $new_user = User::create([
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'oauth_facebook_id' => $provider === 'facebook' ? $user->id : NULL,
            'oauth_twitter_id' => $provider === 'twitter' ? $user->id : NULL,
            'avatar' => $user->avatar,
            'confirmed' => true,
            'gender' => $user->user['gender'],
        ]);

        \Auth::login($new_user, true);

        flash()->success('Success!', 'Your account has been created using your '.ucfirst($provider).' details!');
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

What would be the best way to link the returned details with the current authenticated user?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the user is logged in and then update that user's `oauth_{provider}_id` with the returned data from the provider (`$userData->id`).

Otherwise, create a new user with the returned data.

Something like this:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $userData = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    if(Auth::check()) {

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        if($provider === 'facebook') {
            $user->oauth_facebook_id = $userData->id;
        }

        if($provider === 'twitter') {
            $user->oauth_twitter_id = $userData->id;
        }

        $user->save();

    } else {

        $new_user = User::create([
            'name' => $userData->name,
            'email' => $userData->email,
            'oauth_facebook_id' => $provider === 'facebook' ? $userData->id : NULL,
            'oauth_twitter_id' => $provider === 'twitter' ? $userData->id : NULL,
            'avatar' => $userData->avatar,
            'confirmed' => true,
            'gender' => $userData->user['gender'],
        ]);

        \Auth::login($new_user, true);

        flash()->success('Success!', 'Your account has been created using your '.ucfirst($provider).' details!');

    }

    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: What's the best way to do that? I've tried to do an `if(Auth::check())` block inside my code but as the user is already logged in, it totally bypasses it.

Comment: I've tried the code. When the user is logged in and i go to domain.dev/login/facebook (my URI to trigger socialite code) it just auto redirects me to the dashboard and doesn't update the row at all

Comment: @AndyHolmes It redirects you straight away? Or after going to Facebook?

Comment: Instantly, facebook isnt seen at all

Comment: Done, it's pretty simple :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110749/discussion-between-chris-and-andy-holmes).